# How would I put an if statement inside a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, syntax, indentation

I am very very new to Python and before this I only used extremely simple "programming" languages with labels and gotos. I am trying to make this code work in Sikuli:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXVPv.png

Basically I want it to loop the `if` statement until any of the images is found, and if one of them is found, it executes the right function and starts looping again until it detects a new command.

I have been looking for tutorials and documentation, but I'm really lost. I think my mind is too busy trying to go from a goto/label to an organized programming language.

If someone could give me an example, I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: provide indent in your code in python indentation matter that is `function` next line should be indented

Comment: put your code in your question

Comment: @VigneshKalai Ughh I am so sorry, I didn't know that formatting was actually required... I've never seen that in a programming language before, usually it can still run. I feel like such an idiot now.. well, thanks!

Comment: @SikuliXUser that is not a pronelm learn from your mistake in python indent matter it was difficult for me the first time

Comment: For your future questions, you should put your code directly into the question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Most question python beginners have is anwered in the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python indentation matters, your code should look like this:

```
def function():
    if condition1:
        reaction1() 
    elif condition2:
        reaction2()
    else:
        deafult_reaction()
```

I recommend reading [the chapter about indentation](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) in Dive Into Python as well as [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score -1):

```
x = input("please enter the variable")
print("the Variable entered is " + x)
myfloat = int(x)
def compare(num):
     if num % 2 == 0:
          print("entered variable is even")
     else: 
          print("entered variable is odd")
compare(myfloat)
```

Comment: this code has an infinite loop, but I can't edit it